# Get content from one Wordpress website to another

Tags: images, rss, feed

I have been at this for days and now feel like I am way off track out of desperation and lack of knowledge.  Pretty much I am trying to "scrape" public info from one Wordpress install to a separate Wordpress site.  The sites are on different domains, servers and databases.  Site A (the one I need to grab the content from) uses an RSS Feed which I have been able to successfully pick up.  However each post contains an image ( i dont know if it is featured or not) and I really need to know how to get that image to display.

At first I ran my own loop and was picking up everything aside from the image, then I tried just setting up Simplepie in the theme and still could not get the images to pick up.  Then I was trying a method described on here about XMLRPC and still no luck.  I am about to pull my hair out and I just dont have enough knowledgebase on the subject to get what I need done.

How can I get the feed and image to display from Site A to Site B?  I have read so much stuff I feel like I am so lost.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**

Here is what I have been using which works as far as picking up the feed but not images

```
    <?php function custom_dashboard_feed() {  

    $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://mugshots.starnewsonline.com/feed' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $feed) ):

// Get a maximum of 5 items

$maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity( 5 );

$items = $feed->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

foreach ( $items as $item ):

?>

<p class="rss-widget">

<a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a> <span class="rss-date"><?php echo $item->get_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?></span><br />


<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $item->get_image_url ?>" height="200" width="200" />

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>

</p>

<?php

endforeach;

else: // Returned WP_Error, unable to fetch the feed. ?>

<p>There was an error fetching the feed, please try again later</p>

<?php endif; ?>


<?php
} ?>

<?php $mugshots = custom_dashboard_feed(); echo $mugshots; ?>
```

Comment: Are both of these your websites?

Comment: No, the source is a site that takes public records (like people who have recently been booked and arrested) and puts into a post form.. In other words it is like a "Mugshots" kind of thing..  Even if I were not able to get the images from their RSS feed, I dont know how to go about setting up a similar setup, I asked the IT guys for the Sheriffs office and he said to "scrape" it??

Comment: I don't personally help create scapers but if you want a shot at help, at least post the code you are using for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the old WordPress site go into the admin section then > Tools > Export. Where it says **Choose what to export** check **All content**, and click *Download Export file*.

In the new WordPress site go into the admin section > Tools > Import > choose **WordPress** form the list (it may require you to install the plugin). You can now upload the file form the old WordPress site, and all the content can be ported including images!

Comment: Ahh, my apologies, I dont need to export the content, as this is a live website that updates regularly.. I pretty much need a way to "scrape" the posts they have and new ones.. Because they use Wordpress and RSS and the image is there when you click on each item in the RSS, I figured simplepie or a loop would work, which it does but I cant get the image to come through..

Comment: Can you serve the images from their website?

Comment: I dont fully understand what you mean but when looking at the source the image file path seems to point to the amazon cloud..  like "http://s3.amazon.etc.etc"

Comment: ok, can you give the full url of one of the images?

Comment: sure, rss is http://mugshots.starnewsonline.com/feed and here is an image path: http://nytrmg-mugshots.s3.amazonaws.com/wilmington/images/thumbs/76967f547d08e100217019c53429c19a.jpg

Comment: )Your problems likely come from the RSS feed not having any images. It is possible to do what you want but you would need to write a custom php script. A good starting point would to be to look at the `fopen` function in PHP. [Saving image from PHP URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

Comment: Ok, so you're not actually trying to build a site with the police like you claimed - you're trying to duplicate content from a legitimate site.  And to think some of my questions get closed...

Comment: @AndrettiMilas cut me a break man, this is for a site I am developing for a client and I am just trying to use their public feed to display public information.  I just needed help getting the images and wanted to each out to the community for the best approach.